# Need to do tthis in 1 SQL

Tags: sql

I have to process in an sql as follows. each order is made up of many detail rows. I only need to look at one table, TRA99.

```
Order number   TRAN CODE

123              QEE
123              @23
123              ABC

 SELECT                                    
  ALL       OTRIDC, OTCOM#, OTORD#, OTFL50, OTTRND, OTTRT, OTENT#,    
OTSFX#,                                                               
            OTREL#, OTUSRN, OTTRNC, OTTRN$, OTFL01                    
  FROM      ASTDTA.OETRANOT T01                                       
  WHERE     OTTRNC IN ('QEE', 'QNE')
```

I want all the Order #  which have 'QEE' or 'QNE'. These are QUote codes. We want a report that will tell us, which quotes orders' converted to a real order and which did not.

then if they have as well @23, this tells me that the order was converted or became an actual order. I am not sure how to do this in 1 sql query i was thinking to create a view for all QEE and QNE codes. then run a second query against that looking for @23.

Comment: You need 1 SQL, we need proof of some effort. This is the deal.

Comment: essentially you need all rows where tran code have `'QEE' or 'QNE'` along with `@23`. Just add where condition in your query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I think you're trying to do.  This will give you all the order numbers which are associated with both QEE or QNE and @23

```
    SELECT T1.OrderNumber 
    FROM TRA99 T1
    WHERE T1.OrderNumber in (
                 SELECT OrderNumber
                 FROM TRA99
                 WHERE TCode IN ('QEE','QNE')
                 ) 
    AND T1.TCode='@23'
GROUP BY T1.OrderNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a `GROUP BY` also a `EXISTS` sub-query can check for the existence of your flag

```
select t1.[Order Number]
      ,(CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * 
                         from TRA99 as t2
                         where t1.[Order Number] = t2.[Order Number]
                           and t2.[Tran Code] = '@23')
        THEN
          cast(1 as bit)
        ELSE
          cast(0 as bit)
        END) as HasFlag
from TRA99 as t1
where t1.[Tran Code] in ('QFE', 'QNE')
group by t1.[Order Number]
```

[Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11cf0/1)

NOTE: you did not list what DBMS you are using so I wrote this against Microsoft Sql Server syntax, but you can translate this concept to any DBMS you need.

Comment: db2 ibm i, but i can change its for a crystal report